# Embark + IPFS storage error: Cannot find module 'fs'

Tags: dapp-development, javascript, embark, ipfs

I am using the Embark framework demo code and trying to include IPFS storage (not deployment) functionalities to the project. I get an error message when I try to execute the following code in the browser

```
ipfs.catText("QmZYZyvJeW3eXEiRPS61hvyWSwuHWuSdQRjxmvsD2XqBom", 
       function(err, res) {
           if(err || !res) return console.error(err)
           console.log(res);
    })
```

I have included [ipfs-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipfs-js) from a local folder with `<script src="js/ipfs.js"></script>`

The error is shown in browser console `Error: Cannot find module 'fs'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs` is [node js file system module](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). You have used a script that was meant for node in the browser.

Instead of using this script, you should follow [these instructions](https://github.com/ipfs/js-ipfs-api#in-the-browser-through-script-tag) on how to include the ipfs api in the browser

Comment: I don't understand what the difference is between your suggestion and what I have done. As I say I've included the script through a tag.

In the instructions it says:
`Browser friendly

Run npm install ipfs-js

Or reference dist/ipfs.min.js inside a <script /> to expose the global ipfs`

Comment: Yes, but it seems you have included the wrong script. Did you try including the minified script instead of the node module you linked to?

Comment: Got it working in the end with the Consensys ipfs wrapper.